# Make a sidebar float on a Github wiki (i.e. so that as I scroll down the page it will stay visible)

Tags: github, sidebar

I'd like to make a sidebar float on a Github wiki (i.e. so that as I scroll down the page it will stay visible). Does anyone know how to to this? I don't think you can use CSS or jQuery as per [this post](https://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent a message to Github and got this response:

> It's currently not possible to do that, but I can see how that'd be
>   handy. I can't make any promises regarding implementation, but I'll
>   pass on your feedback for the team to consider!

Comment: Any update on this? I assume this could be possible with a "custom sidebar", didn't find a pre-made solution after a brief search tho.